# Half String every second char

Tags: java, string

I an coding beginner.I have started practicing SPOJ basic problems.[This](http://www.spoj.com/problems/STRHH/) was the one I was trying to solve , But the code is incorrect.

Please help me where I have coded this question wrong as I am unable to figure out:

```
public class Print2ndChar {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Print2ndChar mainObj = new Print2ndChar();

    java.io.BufferedReader inputReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String noOfTestCase;
    if(((noOfTestCase = inputReader.readLine()) == null))
        System.exit(0);
    int noOfLines = 0;

    try{
        noOfLines = Integer.parseInt(noOfTestCase);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(noOfLines<0 || noOfLines>100)
        System.exit(0);

    String [] randomWords = new String[noOfLines];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfLines;i++){
        randomWords[i] = inputReader.readLine();
        if(randomWords[i] == null || randomWords[i].length()<2 ||  randomWords[i].length()%2!=0 || (randomWords[i].length()/2)>100)
            System.exit(0);
    }
    for (String word : randomWords){
        mainObj.letsBegin(word.substring(0, word.length() / 2));
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private void letsBegin(String data) {

    if (data.length() <= 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.print(data.charAt(0));
        if (data.length() >= 3)
            letsBegin(data.substring(2, data.length()));
    }
 }
}
```

EDIT :

I/P : 4
    your
    progress
    is
    noticeable

O/P
    y
    po
    i
    ntc

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is the problem that your are facing?

Comment: @user3765370 The answer is incorrect to the question.May be some negative scenario is missed in coding from what has been asked.I am not able to figure out where this solution is incorrect.

Comment: Can you provide what was your Input set and what was your output.

Comment: You are trying to convert input String, for example "abcdefgh" to Integer
 `noOfLines = Integer.parseInt(noOfTestCase);`
which is wrong, it causes Exception.

Comment: @WrongRhyme kept in try and catch.So if wrong input is provided it won't proceed further as it does not meet the condition specified in the problem statement.

Comment: The output you provided seems fine.

Comment: Yeah..but something is wrong..

Comment: @xyz - sorry I misread the problem specification. However, there is nothing wrong with your output. After input words "your" "progress" "is" "noticeable" the output should be "y" "po" "i" "ntc". There is nothing wrong with the output you mentioned.

Comment: @arjan sure..will fix this too.

Comment: @arjan my mistake with that answer. Actually nothing wrong with the code if it is giving the expected output.

Comment: @xyz - you didn't say what is wrong with the output, what is it that you are asking us. "Something is wrong" is very vague. What do you expect to be the output of "your" "progress" "is" "noticeable" when you say "y" "po" "i" "ntc" is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! So after a lot of hit and trials, I know what is wrong with your code. The code that you have written fails because of the condition `randomWords[i].length()%2!=0` inside your `if`. There is nothing wrong with you putting this condition to check the input, but if you will select sample test case, inside the highlighted blue area you will notice an extra space after every string. Like this :

[image]

You can see that other than the last input all other input strings have a space character at the end. So, when you read the string from `stdin` the length of the string is `2*k + 1` (because of the space), and your program will exit without any output. Hence you get a wrong answer.

This problem exists with other test cases as well probably. And how do I know this? After spoj shows you **wrong answer**, if you click on the **wrong answer**, it will show you 2 failed test cases, something like this:

[image]
It shows your program's output is empty because your code exited because of the extra space at the end of strings.
So, I believe the person who wrote the test cases should be given a **WT** Error (Wrong Test Cases) :P :D

So, the possible correction is you remove the mentioned condition from the `if` and you will get AC. Because now you will be dividing `2*k + 1` by `2`, which will not be an integer and which will get rounded to the nearest smallest integer, which will be same as dividing `2*k` by `2` and the program will give the correct result.

A few things that you should take care while solving questions on spoj, you do not have to verify that every input lies within the range specified in the question, or if it is a valid data type. The range is given to tell you that Spoj will only test your program with cases which lie between those ranges and will not exceed them. So, even if you remove all the code where you check for exceptions and ranges of input data, you will get an AC. Moreover, writing such code only adds to the burden.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: also thanks to telling me about the test case which was failing it.It would be easy test and fix now :)

Comment: @xyz Well, I don't think spoj usually shares the details of failed test cases, it was just for this question, or probably some others.